# Firestore js Query asking to create Index key Every time

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```js
db.collection('messages')
  .doc(member_id)
  .collection(therapist_id)
  .where('is_deleted','==', false)
  .orderBy('is_deleted')
  .orderBy('message_timestamp');
```

Response i am getting is

**

> async_observer.ts:47 Uncaught Error in snapshot listener:
> FirebaseError: The query requires an index. You can create it here:

**

This is my firestore query and it is always askig to create index key manually i dont want to create every time is thera any way to overcome this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately but composite indexes are only created when you ask for them and they can't be created automatically.

The error message should contain a link directly to the console to complete that task.

Comment: So is there any solution to run this query in firebase ?

Comment: You can use [Firebase Console](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing#use_the_firebase_console) directly instead of clicking error message.